# convert numbers to words in a easy way

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

write a function num_to_word that takes num as a parameter, this function should convert the parameter to string. FOR EXAMPLE num_to_word(234) should return two three four.
 please help me.

```
def num_to_word(num):
    result = ''
    literals = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    num = num.str()
    for i in range (0, len(num)):
        result += literals[num[i]] + ' '
    return result;

num_to_word(1390)
```

this is the error am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
  File "python", line 4, in num_to_word
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: Please do share what you've tried so far & what error you're getting.

Comment: function num_to_word(num) {
  var result = '';
  var literals = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
  num = num.toString();

  for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    result += literals[num[i]] + ' ';
  }

  return result;
}
num_to_word(1390)

Comment: that my code in javascript , i want to convert it to python

Comment: Would be great if you add it in your question, your whole query. And what you've done so far, the error you got, stacktrace also.

Comment: i have posted a javascript code working well, i want to change the same to python but i am unable

Comment: def num_to_word(num):
    result = ''
    literals = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    num = num.str()
    for i in range (0, len(num)):
        result += literals[num[i]] + ' '
    return result;

num_to_word(1390)

Comment: this is the error am getting:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
  File "python", line 4, in num_to_word
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: my code is: def num_to_word(num):
    result = ''
    literals = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    num = num.str()
    for i in range (0, len(num)):
        result += literals[num[i]] + ' '
    return result;

num_to_word(1390)       the error i am getting is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
  File "python", line 4, in num_to_word
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @Davis muriungi, just edit your initial post.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko please let me know how?

Comment: @Davis muriungi, [here](http://imgur.com/mSZnaE9).

Comment: @IvanGritsenko i think i have done it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, Works quite well for me.

```
def num_to_word(num):
    num_dict = {'0': 'zero', '1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three', '4': 'four', '5': 'five', '6': 'six', '7': 'seven', '8': 'eight', '9': 'nine'}
    return ' '.join([num_dict[x] for x in str(num)])
```

Comment: what if i want it to print num after conversion

Comment: user 'print' instead of 'return'.

Comment: def num_to_word(num):
    num_dict = {'0': 'zero', '1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three', '4': 'four', '5': 'five', '6': 'six', '7': 'seven', '8': 'eight', '9': 'nine'}
    print ' '.join([num_dict[x] for x in str(num)])
num_to_word(345)                  i have done it that way but i get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3
    print ' '.join([num_dict[x] for x in str(num)])
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax instead of three four five

Comment: what data did u pass to the function?

EDIT: Jus saw that. Let me check.

Comment: num_to_word(345)  i want it to print three four five

Answer (score 0):

There were few mistakes. I have modified your code, you should be good to go.

`int.str()` is not a python function, and when you have converted an int to a string, the `literal[num[i]]` will be `literal[string]` and that is where the error was. And you will need print at the call to see the result.

```
def num_to_word(num):
    result = ''
    literals = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    num = str(num)
    for i in range(len(num)):
        result += literals[int(num[i])] + ' '
    return result

print num_to_word(1390)
```